# Check if entity contains all components through enum flags

Tags: c#

I'm struggling a bit to understand the iteration piece here of how I would check if if the `entity` variable below has **all** of the `Enum.Component` entries in the variable `comps`.  I can achieve this relatively straight-forwardly if I know there will be only one Component via a `.ForEach` and a basic comparison (e.g. `entity.ForEach(comp => Console.WriteLine(comp.COMPONENT == Enum.Component.EXPERIENCE));`), but not if I need to check for multiple components.

I'm trying to understand the nuances of C# a bit better, so I don't want to brute force this with an actual `foreach` (in the conventional `foreach(var x in exes)` type of way) or something similar, but really want to understand how I would implement this via these objects through these `IEnumerable` functions and working with lambda expressions.  As such, I need an answer utilizing these things, unless of course this is not technically possible, though probably it is, I'm guessing.

```
// The Component.IComponent Interface (it's in the Component namespace)
interface IComponent {
    Enum.Component COMPONENT {
        get;
    }
}

// The Enum.Component (it's in the Enum namespace)
enum Component {
    EXPERIENCE,
    HEALTH
}

// The Component.Experience (it's in the Component namespace)
class Experience : IComponent {
    public ThresholdValue xp;
    public int level;

    public Enum.Component COMPONENT {
        get {
            return Enum.Component.EXPERIENCE;
        }
    }
}

// It probably doesn't matter, but ENTITY_MANAGER is this type
Dictionary<Guid, List<Component.IComponent>>


// Trial code beings here:
Guid GUID = new Guid();
ENTITY_MANAGER.getEntities().Add(GUID, new List<Component.IComponent> { new Component.Experience(50, 3), new Component.Health(20, 25) });
List<Component.IComponent> entity = ENTITY_MANAGER.getEntities()[new Guid()];

Enum.Component[] comps = new Enum.Component[] {
    Enum.Component.EXPERIENCE,
    Enum.Component.HEALTH
};

// This is where I don't know what to do and know this is wrong
comps.All(v => entity.ForEach(comp => Console.WriteLine(comp.COMPONENT == v)));
```

Comment: You can use select in entity! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj573936(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this via Flags!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

First do this with your Enum:

```
[Flags]
enum Component {
    None = 0,
    EXPERIENCE = 1 << 0,
    HEALTH = 1 << 1,
    All = (1 << 2) - 1
}
```

This basically will store your values as powers of 2, with 'All' being the sum of all your flags, in this case Exp and Hp are 1 and 2, so All is 3 (1+2)

Now you can just do this in your entity class:

```
public  Enum.Component Flags => comps.Select(c => c.Component).Distinct().Sum();
public bool HasAllFlags => Flags == Enum.Component.All;
```

We make our enum all distinct base 2, with all the next step -1, which means All is the sum of all your enum listings.

Then we just sum up the Enums (We might have to convert to an int first then back to the enum, I don't remember if you can just add Enums together in C#) and check if they == Component.All.

There you go!

Comment: Thanks for the help, that `[Flags]` attribute really helped.  I kept getting a "`comps` not available in this scope" type of error, but was able to use your suggestion at a higher level to accomplish the task thus:`Enum.Component flags = Enum.Component.EXPERIENCE | Enum.Component.HEALTH;
            Enum.Component mask = (Enum.Component)entity.Sum(e => (int)e.COMPONENT);

            Console.WriteLine((mask & flags) == flags);`